# Manage User Access by IP

Tags: 7

I am building an "Extranet" (Company Intranet, available both inside and outside our network).

What I want is three levels of authorization... Authorized (via LDAP AD), guest inside network and guest outside network.

Guest inside and Guest outside is where I'm getting hung up.

For users inside the network, I want "Public" stuff accessible (along with departmental stuff, depending on user signed in). For users outside the network I want a blank screen to show up until the user logs in (with proper AD credentials).

So a "Guest" inside the network should have access to stuff without logging in... a "guest" outside the network needs to log in before anything shows up.

I've seen some stuff that will "Ban" or "Whitelist" based on IP (since all the "inside" computers will be 192.168 or 10.10), but they don't seem to grant the ability to "greylist" (ban until logged in?).

I'm thinking maybe Themekey, with a separate theme for outside-unauthorized? Or would it be better to roll something up myself?

Answer (score 0):

[Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) might be what your looking for. you have to find a module that plugs into rules that can check ip.